# Laravel isNotEmpty() not working on Eloquent model

Tags: laravel

I'm probably confused by Eloquent (again...) but I thought that this should work:

```
$test_row = Test::
            where('status', 'active')
            ->where('condition2', 'value')
            ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
            ->first();

        if($test_row->isNotEmpty())
            return $test_row;
```

But is it throwing the following error: `Call to undefined method App\Test::isNotEmpty()`.

By using `first()` it will return an Eloquent model right? And `isNotEmpty()`, as well as `isEmpty()`, should be able to be used on the returned model?

Comment: Eloquent may return `null` on a query if no result could've been found.

Comment: [isNotEmpty](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) is helper method of laravel collections and you are using it over another helper that is why you get exception , In order to work with you can remove `->first()` from your query builder object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`isNotEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-isnotempty) is actually returned by Laravels [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) class and not by an Eloquent model. Since you're not asking for multiple results, only the model is returned instead of a collection.

Simply use

```
if ($test_row) {
    return $test_row;
}
```

to check if the query had any results and the model exists.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call isNotEmpty() on a model object and not a collection, when you use first() it returns an object not a collection.

Use

```
if($test_row)
{
    return $test_row
}
```